# Как отправить значение data аяксом

Tags: javascript

```
 BX24.callMethod('crm.deal.list', {
            filter: {
                ID: id,
            },
            select: ["CONTACT_ID"]
        },
        function(result)
        {
            if(result.error())
                console.error(result.error());
            else
            {
                console.dir(result.data());
                if(result.more())
                    result.next();
            }
        }
    );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данные мне приходят в таком формате, как мне отправить значение CONTACT_ID аяксом ?

Answer (score 0):

```
BX24.callMethod('crm.deal.list', {
            filter: {
                ID: id,
            },
            select: ["CONTACT_ID"]
        },
        function(result)
        {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "http",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {idContact: result.data()},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(er) {
                    console.log(er);
                }
            });
        }
    );
```